# Canceling Threads

Tags: c#

I have an application that uses 20 threads. It's an email client that uses threads to mail from.

Currently the threads are created in the main thread. But I am wondering, what if I want to cancel the whole operation? The only way I can see of doing it is killing the main thread ... thus ending the program.

Would I have to create a thread that encapsulates the threads for mailing so I can kill the encapsulating thread?

I am currently using BackgroundWorker by the way and it's a WF application.

Comment: You have 20 Backgroundworker threads or using it to lauch other threads

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a `BackgroundWorker` then you already have all of the infrastructure you need to cancel the operation.  Simply set `WorkerSupportsCancellation` to `true` on the `BackgroundWorker`, and invoke the worker's `CancelAsync` method when you want to cancel.

Obviously you have to write the worker code to honour the cancellation.  You do this by checking the `CancellationPending` property of the `BackgroundWorker`.

MSDN has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) of using this property.

---

Note - I am a bit confused by the combination of `BackgroundWorker` and 20 threads; a `BackgroundWorker` only uses one thread by itself.  Are you spinning off 20 `BackgroundWorkers`?  If so, how do you ensure that they're properly disposed?  If you need that much concurrency in a Winforms app then it's better to use asynchronous delegates or the Thread Pool.

If you are creating actual threads, one common way of implementing a cancellation flag is to use a `ManualResetEvent`.  If you wait on this event with zero timeout, it acts as a thread-safe status flag.  An example usage would be:

```
ManualResetEvent cancelEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
    {
        // Do some work
        if (cancelEvent.WaitOne(0, true))
            return;
        // Do some more work
        // etc.
    });
}
```

Then at some point later if you write `cancelEvent.Set()`, every worker will stop its work as soon as it hits the status check.

Comment: Yes but wont that just cancel the current thread? Each thread is set to email a selected set of emails from the companies database. So if I was to cancel that thread, the other 19 would still be alive right?