# How to set_WorkerSupportsCacellation for backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I'm having a problem in my code that you the backgroundWorker gets started twice.  Therefore, I'm trying to set_WorkerSupportsCacellation so I can cancel the thread if `backgroundWorker1.IsBusy` with `backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync`.  However, when I do the following:

```
this.backgroundWorker1.set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(true);
```

I get a compilation error:

'System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation.set': cannot explicitly call oprator or accessor

Does anyone know how I can set this to true?

I googled the problem but don't see the answer to this.  So far I found the following links that weren't helpful:  [Canceling Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383840/canceling-threads)
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/using-the-backgroundworker-component/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where `set_WorkerSupportsCancellation(true)` comes from, but the call should be :

```
 backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Comment: I tried that, and now it's saying I cannot explicitly call operator or accessor.  I'm not sure how to set it then.  It's probably a hidden thing on the property menu to set, but I'm not seeing it.  Examples I see are showing what you said to do here.

Comment: @Michele show more code then - there must be something else going on

Comment: I figured it out.  See below.  My background worker is on my class [Design] menu screen, so maybe that's why.  There wasn't really any more code to post.  On my Design screen, I went to properties, and finally found where to set it to true.  Now it builds with it set.

Comment: @Michele you can still set it programmatically as above.  The line I posted above is not an operator or accessor so I find it hard to believe that you tried it exactly as written.  The above works.

Answer (score 2):

In a C# program it is considered an error, if you explicitly invoke property setter/getters (the compiler generated methods) or methods to which C# operators are mapped.

Comment: As J... has shown you... What, that does not work either? That can't be, there must be something else in your code causing that error.

Answer (score 0):

I see it.  On the properties window, there was a selection for WorkerSupportsCancellation and I set it to true.  Whew!!  Thanks for the help!